# chase has locked my account can i do?

Tags: bank-account

I have a tenant that been waiting for months to get her unemployment she finally got it and she didn't have her own account and was getting ready to go out of state to take care of her mom who is dying of covid so she endorsed 4 checks to me and I deposited them in my account there was a hold 4 7 days they cashed them into my account and now the put restriction on my account and there saying that she has to come into bank with her id before I can have access to my money she's out of state and doesn't plan on coming back for a couple of months anybody knows what I can do????? I have a mortgage to pay.

Comment: She can't go to a branch location that is closer to her? Chase is a nation-wide bank...

Comment: No, she is out in the middle of nowhere. There aren't any banks there's a general store and a mobile post office that's it. They are also all quarantined due to Covid she's there taking care of her mother who is extremely sick.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very difficult problem without a clear solution.  You would have had a similar problem had she died.

I live in an area much like your tenant's mom.  The county I live in is as large as Rhode Island.  The response time for emergency services can be 90 minutes in some areas.  There is generally no cell service and often no internet.

Your tenant's quarantine period will start the day her mother's ends and run for ten days if she has no symptoms.  If she has symptoms, then the clock would start on the day of the first symptom.  If she really is dying, then her mother's isolation period could run as long as 20 days instead of the normal 10.

This problem that you are having is not unique to you.  There have been problems with frozen accounts nationwide relating to unemployment checks.

I would begin with the local bank's branch manager.  The problem that you are facing is that if you were a fraudster, then you could easily come up with this story.  However, if you have deposited rent checks in the past, from before when your tenant was unemployed, then they could see the signature on her checks.

If they have multiple examples of her signature paying for rent, and, better still, a signed rental agreement, you may have luck getting the account unfrozen.

The difficulty will be that they have a written policy.  If it were a small town, locally owned bank, where you have had a very long relationship, then you might have a better chance.

They may also accept a zoom meeting if it is possible.  If they won't accept her alone, a local unemployment office may also be willing to be involved.

The next alternative would be to complain to whatever supervisory agency regulates the bank.  It will be in their mandatory signage.  It may not be helpful as I believe they are a national bank.  Given the strong emphasis on anti-money-laundering actions, they might not help at all.  If it is incorporated as something other than a branch of a national bank, such as a state bank, then you may be able to get some headway.

If your mortgage is with the same bank, they may be able to "pay" your mortgage payment by putting your account into overdraft.  After all, if the funds are valid, then they already have the money on hand.  If the funds are bad, then they can just reverse the payments and put you into default.

Other than that, you will probably need an attorney.

The bank has two fears.  The first is the obvious fraud, the second is that some states have completely messed up their unemployment claims and are asking for the money back.

Comment: "I would begin with the local bank's branch manager." - Yes, the landlord's local branch. Demand that they figure out the ID issue (maybe via Facetime with the tenant) or remove the problem deposits. Whatever it takes to unlock the landlord's account.

Answer (score -4):

Here's a "frame challenge" answer. A bigger problem than just getting through this month is continuing to deal with an unreliable tenant.

It may sound heartless, but as a landlord you are running a business. Rents are rising in most of the US, indicating growing demand from qualified tenants.

The eviction moratorium is over almost everywhere in the nation. The fact that your tenant has been "waiting for months to get her unemployment" is her problem, not yours.

When she got behind on rent for whatever reason, she was in violation of the lease. Moreover, the lease should specify the means of rent payment, and typically third-party checks are not accepted.

Consider also that the tenant might be exaggerating her hardship for sympathy (of course disregard this if you have direct knowledge of her situation).

Bottom line, don't be afraid to use your power as a landlord. Evicting someone can be complicated and time-consuming, but perhaps you can make a deal for her to leave quickly and quietly in exchange for forgiving some of the arrears.

Then focus on getting someone who has no trouble paying the rent in full every month like clockwork. Lots of people have good incomes and have been priced out of buying by the hot housing market.

Comment: Well I was happy with my rent before she left the state and she didn't have any way to cash them just 2 weeks before this my tenant endorsed 3 of the first checks she got and they cashed them no problem  then all of a sudden I put four more in they didn't say anything about not doing it they could have just sent the checks back to her but instead when they cleared they cashed them into my account